# How do I set max character length of filenames?

Tags: vb.net

I am currently using the following code to remove the defined special characters and white spaces from any file names within my defined directory:

```
        For Each file As FileInfo In files
            newName = Regex.Replace(file.Name, "[!@#$%^&*()_ ]", "")
            If (file.Name <> newName) Then
                newPath = Path.Combine(dir, newName)
                file.CopyTo(newPath)
            End If
        Next
```

Edit: How do I trim the characters of the new file name (newName) to all but the first 26 characters?

Answer:

```
For Each file As FileInfo In files
            If (file.Name.Length >= 36) Then
                Dim maxLen As Integer = 26 - file.Extension.Length
                newName = ${Regex.Replace(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name), "[!@#$%^&*()_ ]",
                                    "").Substring(0, maxLen)}{file.Extension}"
                newPath = Path.Combine(dir, newName)
                file.CopyTo(newPath, True)
            ElseIf (file.Name.Length < 36) Then
                newName = Regex.Replace(file.Name, "[!@#$%^&*()_ ]", "")
                If (file.Name <> newName) Then
                    newPath = Path.Combine(dir, newName)
                    file.CopyTo(newPath)
                End If
            End If
        Next
```

Comment: What are you ACTUALLY asking? a file name is a `String`. Are you asking how to trim all but the first 26 characters from a `String`? It's up to you to analyse your problem and determine the specific issue you're having. The question you have asked is actually far broader then you think.

Comment: You can use `If-Else` statement to prompt user or you can just trim the string. It depends on what you want.

Comment: My apologies for the original broadness or vagueness of my initial question. I've since edited, but yes - I am looking to trim all but the first 26 characters of the "newName".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Linq as follows:

```vb
Dim dir = "c:\myFolder"
Dim except = "[!@#$%^&*()_ ]".ToArray

For Each file As FileInfo In files
    Dim maxLen As Integer = 26 - file.Extension.Length
    Dim newPath = Path.Combine(dir,
                        $"{New String(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name).
                        ToCharArray.
                        Except(except).
                        Take(maxLen).
                        ToArray)}{file.Extension}")

    file.CopyTo(newPath, True)
Next
```

Suppose you have a file with name:

```
abcdefg_hijk!lm@pno#pq%r(stuvy)x$z.dbf
```

The newPath output will be:

```
c:\myFolder\abcdefghijklmpnoqrstuv.dbf
```

If that is what you need to do.

---

**Edit:**

Alternative using RegEx:

```vb
Dim except = "[!@#$%^&*()_ ]"

For Each file As FileInfo In files
    Dim maxLen As Integer = 26 - file.Extension.Length
    Dim newName = $"{Regex.Replace(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name),
                                    except,
                                    "").Substring(0, maxLen)}{file.Extension}"
    Dim newPath = Path.Combine(dir, newName)
    file.CopyTo(newPath, True)
Next
```

So the `newPath` for a file with name:

```
n_BrucesMiddle NH 12 34 5 W3_H.dbf
```

... will be:

```
c:\myFolder\nBrucesMiddleNH12345W3.dbf
```

The unwanted characters have been removed and the maximum length of the new file name (`newName`) including the extension is 26.

Here's [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Ou5ruY/10) example.

Again, if that is what you need. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this out, but I noticed it changed the file names beyond just the characters/white spaces I need to remove. Example: "n_BrucesMiddle NH 12 34 5 W3_H" became nBrucesMidlNH1234W? Why is this occuring? - I'm quite new to this and perhaps not wording my questions well, but in reality, in addition to removing special characters and white spaces, I really just need to shorten any file name (not including the extensions) to a maximum of 26 characters. Just the end of the filename can be removed if it surpasses. Otherwise, if the filename is shorter it does not need to be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Use [String.Remove](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/trimming)

```
newName = newName.Remove(26)
```

**Note that:** string length should be greater than or equal to 26

EDIT:
If you want the extension to remain. use this instead:

```
newName = newName.Remove(26, newName.length - 30)
```

Comment: Is there a means of not including the extension in the count of 26? For example, "abcdefghijklmpnopqrstuvyxz.dbf" is 30 characters long, but calling to remove anything beyond 26 removes the extension and the file.copy fails.

Answer (score 1):

To rename files you can use `.MoveTo` method.
From the docs:

> Moves a specified file to a new location, providing the option to
>   specify a new file name.

You probably want to rename only the "name" part so extension remain unchanged.
This approach will support any file extension (not only extension with 3 characters)

```
For Each file As FileInfo In files
    Dim newName As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name).Remove(26)

    Dim newPath = Path.Combine(file.DirectoryName, $"{newName}{file.Extension}")
    file.MoveTo(newPath)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to get a subset of a String, you would get the [Substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.8). If you want the first 26 characters it would be the second overload.

Example:

```
Dim filename As String = "this is a terrible f^ln@me! that is (way) too long.txt"
Dim newFilename As String = Regex.Replace(filename, "[!@#$%^&*()_ ]", String.Empty).Substring(0, 26)
```

Live Demo: [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3vfVk0)

**Update**

As per your comment, here is how you'd trim down just the filename without the extension:

```
Dim filename As String = "this is a terrible f^ln@me! that is (way) too long.txt"
Dim extension As String = Path.GetExtension(filename)
Dim shortFilename As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename)
Dim newFilename As String = Regex.Replace(shortFilename, "[!@#$%^&*()_ ]", String.Empty).Substring(0, 26) & extension
```

Live Demo: [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IpgqO3)

Comment: Is there a way of excluding the extension from the substring count? For example, "abcdefghijklmpnopqrstuvyxz.dbf" is 30 characters long, but calling the substring of (0, 26) removes the extension and the file.copy fails.

Comment: Before trimming down the String you will want to convert the string to a Path. Once you have the path, you can get the extension, trim down your String to 26 characters, and then append the extension back.